# drag(rearrange) table row using jquery.sortable. js And angular. js integration issue

Tags: jquery, .net, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i am using mvc 4 api project.  i have integrated angularjs in it so i use single page application.

i was looking for inline editing support for grid.  but i dint go with ngGrid.  so now i m using angular-xeditable.  its a cool library but seems like no support from author.

i want to achieve inline editing, sorting, pagination and filtering plus movable rows of grid.. these are prime requirements of project.  currently i do crud operation using angular-xeditable.

1) is there anything new cool which can full fill my requirements? i have checked ngTable, smartTable, ngGrid,  dataTable...  but inline editing way is so cool with angular-xeditable...

I dont think i will get support from its author. still i have decided to go with angular-xeditable.

2) what if i want to add sorting and filtering with angular-xeditable inline ROW editing????  any way suggestions?

3)
in my index. cshtml page
i have included

```
jquery. js
jquery. ui. js
angular. js
jquery-sortable. js
jquery-dataTable. js
```

in my controller i have written

$('#sortId'). sortable().....

$('#sortId'). dataTable()....

but it throws error in angular. js like 'object doesnt support sortable method'. 
'object doesnt support dataTable method'.

Note: all js versions are latest.

Comment: Try loading `jquery-sortable.js` and `jquery-dataTable.js` before `angular.js`..?

Comment: did it.  not working...  even i wonder why it is not working?